Highmap with overlaid pie chart series
I am looking to create a highmap with overlaid piecharts based on this JSfiddle. I have used the events = list(load = JS() construct to call the JS code, copied from the demo above. The problem I have, as shown below, is that the output contains only a single piechart, whereas it should include a piechart for each non-missing point in the series.
Additionally, I note that the pie chart renders in the centre of the map, but the tooltip and data is for the last point of the data series - here SE (Sweden, I think!). It is also significant that the pie chart always renders in the same spot, regardless of the id of the last country of data. What am I doing wrong here? I attach an image of the output below, as well as the code to replicate the map.

Update
Thanks to Felix Jassler's comment I realised that each individual pie chart is in fact being plotted, but the problem is then that they all plotted in the same place. Enabling labels on the pie chart makes this clear to see, as shown in the updated image output below. Additionally, I have also since found this post, where a user on highcharts in vue.JS encountered the exact same problem. The solution here was the user to update to the latest version of highcharts v10.2. I have the latest version of highcharter (v9.4), and so I think that that solution would probably require some input from the developers of highcharter. I have opened an issue here on the highcharter git.
Final update
The answer given below by jedrzerjuta has been accepted with much gratitude and the result can be seen below.

# Required
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

# Create data
data <- tibble(
  id = c(
    "PL",
    "NO",
    "DE",
    "BY",
    "FR",
    "CZ",
    "SE"
  ),
  successes = c(
    15,
    20,
    10,
    10,
    1,
    20,
    20
  ),
  failures = c(
    3,
    2,
    10,
    15,
    2,
    20,
    8
    
  )
)
data$value <- data$successes-data$failures

# Plot
hcmap("custom/world-highres",
      data = data,
      joinBy = c("iso-a2", "id"),
      keys =c('id', 'successes', 'failures', 'value')
)%>%
  hc_colorAxis(
    dataClasses=list(
      list(
        from = -15,
        to = -1,
        color = '#faa',
        name = 'Successes'
      ),
      list(
        from = 0,
        to = 0,
        color = '#ddd',
        name = 'Neutral'
      ),
      list(
        from = 1,
        to = 18,
        color = '#adf',
        name = 'Neutral'
      )
    )
  )%>%
  hc_chart(events = list(load = JS("function() {
  var chart = this;
  chart.series[0].points.forEach(country => {
  if (!country.isNull) {
    chart.addSeries({
      type: 'pie',
      name: country.id,
      zIndex: 4,
      size: 40,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      onPoint: {
        id: country.id
      },
      states: {
        inactive: {
          enabled: true
        }
      },
      data: [{
        name: 'Successes',
        y: country.successes,
        color: '#adf'
      }, {
        name: 'Failures',
        y: country.failures,
        color: '#faa'
      }]
    }, false);
  }
        }
        );
  chart.redraw();
}
"
  )
  )
  )



Minor note, from the generated html I believe all pie charts are generated, they are just sitting on top of each other. Maybe there's a way to set their positions.

@FelixJassler Thanks for pointing this out. You are right, when I hover over the pie in the HTML I can see tooltips for both SE and CZ. So it seems that the problem relates to the positioning of the pies; apparently the onPoint command of the JS section is not working as I expect it too. I will examine this option in more detail and hopefully can find a solution. Thanks again!

The problem with the pie charts not being laid on countries coordinates is strictly linked to Highcharts v9.3.1 being used in the latest Highcharter version available on CRAN. Above code uses onPoint object property, which requires series-on-point module, that is available from Highcharts > v10 version.
As a workaround, you can install the development version from Highcharter GitHub repository: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter?tab=readme-ov-file#installation and add the series-on-point module using highcharter::hc_add_dependency method. This version uses Highcharts v10.2.0, so it should work correctly.
Below you will find updated R code:
# Required
library(tidyverse)
remotes::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")

# Create data
data <- tibble(
  idd = c(
    "PL",
    "NO",
    "DE",
    "BY",
    "FR",
    "CZ",
    "SE"
  ),
  successes = c(
    15,
    20,
    10,
    10,
    1,
    20,
    20
  ),
  failures = c(
    3,
    2,
    10,
    15,
    2,
    20,
    8
    
  )
)
data$value <- data$successes-data$failures

# Plot
highcharter::hcmap("custom/world-highres",
      data = data,
      joinBy = c("iso-a2", "idd"),
      keys =c('idd', 'successes', 'failures', 'value')#,
      #dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = "{point.idd}",
      #style=list(fontSize='10'))
)%>%
  highcharter::hc_add_dependency("modules/series-on-point.js")%>%
  highcharter::hc_colorAxis(
    dataClasses=list(
      list(
        from = -15,
        to = -1,
        color = '#faa',
        name = 'Successes'
      ),
      list(
        from = 0,
        to = 0,
        color = '#ddd',
        name = 'Neutral'
      ),
      list(
        from = 1,
        to = 18,
        color = '#adf',
        name = 'Neutral'
      )
    )
  )%>%
  highcharter::hc_chart(events = list(load = highcharter::JS("function() {
  var chart = this;
  chart.series[0].points.forEach(country => {
  if (!country.isNull) {
    chart.addSeries({
      type: 'pie',
      name: country.idd,
      zIndex: 6,
      size: 40,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
      onPoint: {
        id: country.id
      },
      states: {
        inactive: {
          enabled: true
        }
      },
      data: [{
        name: 'Successes',
        y: country.successes,
        color: '#adf'
      }, {
        name: 'Failures',
        y: country.failures,
        color: '#faa'
      }]
    }, false);
  }
        }
        );
  chart.redraw();
}
"
  )
  )
  )


@jedrzerjuta This does the trick! Thank you very much. I think it worth highlighting that even when using the development version the pies only render correct when hc_add_dependency is included. I have accepted your answer, and again thank you!
